# Why camera plugin requires storage access on Android?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, camera, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I am unable to understand why storage access is required for the camera plugin to work on android. If i do not have give storage access and want only the camera to work why cant i do that? Currently i must have to give storage access

Comment: Because Camera plugin also have a functionality to Select Photos from Photo Library. that's why this plugins asks for storage access.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that Camera can access storage to save photos.  Rather than implicitly granting access to storage via camera access you are required to explicitly grant storage access.

Comment: I understand that but if i dont want to use the library option i deny the storage request i still should be able to use camera only. Currently i have to allow storage access to use camera even if i dont want to use photo library

Comment: I am stating the obvious I know, but it would seem the Android designers didn't design it so you can access the camera without storage, and because of this they have to protect the users data by forcing you to request a grant for storage access.  Not really something we can resolve on SO.  Perhaps you might have some luck suggesting a feature request for them to support your needs at https://source.android.com/setup/contribute/report-bugs